# Android textview over imageview with background transparent

Tags: android, textview, imageview, transparent

Please let me know how to add textview over imageview with background transparent as per image. Detail is I want to add two textview over imageview, one textview is title and the rest one is description. And background is transparent. Please help.[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should use merge tag in xml of your layout.. For example [Merge example](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html)

Comment: Please, post the relevant part of the answer not just a link.

Answer (score 3):

one possible way: add Framelayout as root and then add textview and imageview like this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/golden_gate" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"

    android:padding="12dip"

    android:background="#AA000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"

    android:text="Golden Gate" />

 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: explanation: http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html

Comment: Perfect. Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a FrameLayout as container and to overlay TextView on the ImageView and assign a background of lower alpha channel #AARRGGBB

Answer (score 0):

You set the image as a background of your layout parent, for example RelativeLayout, and then you put and other layout with background transparent in the bottom of the first layout.
Then we put your textView inside the second layout.